# Book where a kid saves a superhero, gains healing powers after taking a blast, then finds the hero has taken credit

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, super-hero

I read this book back about 5 years ago in my freshman year of highschool and it was in English.

This kid really loves this superhero and he and his friends usually fight about who gets to play him in this really high tech game. The kid helps save his hero one day when some villains were trying to humiliate and kill the hero.

The kid finds out he has a super healing ability after he emerges from a cocoon after taking the blast hit from the villains attack. His powers only healed himself. If he got hurt it would scab off and flake away to reveal perfectly healed skin.

He ends up going to this school and later finds out that the hero had taken credit for his save and painted him as a helpless victim.

I've been wracking my brain trying to find this book.

Comment: I’m sorry I do not have an answer, but I’ve been searching for years as well, maybe if we can keep putting the stuff we remember into google it will be easier to find. I remember the character Howler and the bronze girl in their super Hero school.

Answer (score -1):

ive been looking for the book for a long time as well and just recently found it, its called school for sidekicks

Comment: Any extra details you could [edit] in to help motivate why you believe this is what the OP is looking for? Does the main character have healing abilities?